# Is there a known bitmap scaling algorithm that produces the same result as this algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, bitmap, scaling

My algorithm for scaling a bitmap *b* of size *w1* × *h1* to a bitmap of size *w2* × *h2*:

1. scale *b* to a bitmap *b1* of size lcm(*w1*, *w2*) × lcm(*h1*, *h2*) using nearest-neighbor scaling algorithm;
2. partition *b1* to a grid that have *w2* columns and *h2* rows where all columns have the same width and all rows have the same height;
3. set the color of every pixel in *b1* to the **average color** of the pixel's belonging grid cell;
4. scale the modified *b1* to a bitmap *b2* of size *w2* × *h2* using nearest-neighbor scaling algorithm;
5. The bitmap *b2* is the result of this algorithm.

The algorithm above is not the most efficient one to get the result. I only use it to describe the effect of the scaling algorithm (and I can do it in Photoshop instead of writing a program). Is there a known algorithm that produces the same result as mine?

Comment: It sounds an awful lot like a roundabout way to do bilinear interpolation.

Comment: @beaker I don't think bilinear interpolation does the same job. When the target size is an integer multiple of the original size, my algorithm is equivalent to nearest-neighbor interpolation. Does bilinear interpolation has this feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a detailed description here: http://entropymine.com/imageworsener/pixelmixing/.

> It’s sometimes called pixel mixing, pixel averaging, or area map, among other things.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your algorithm is that it will take a lot of memory.  As an example, if you scale from a size of 11x11 to 13x13, the least common multiple (lcm) of 11 and 13 is 143.  You will therefore create a 143x143 image, and then reduce it to 13x13.

As an alternative, have a look at "bilinear interpolation": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation (this article also gives other methods in the "See also" section).

Comment: I know there are lots of good scaling algorithms, and I already knew a way to reduce the memory consumption, but it's a little complicated. I think the algorithm I described is easier to understand. Maybe my question is misleading. My algorithm doesn't matter, it's the result that matters. I want to know if there is a known algorithm that produces the same result as mine.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know.